# How to use kafka on tornado?

Tags: python, tornado, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I'm trying to make a simple chat app using tornado based on [this](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/tree/stable/demos/chat)

But also I want to use kafka to store the messages. How can I do that?

Now, I used [this](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka) to make a consumer and somehow it's working but it's only printing on the console and I need the messages to show on the webpage, like the tornade app, only it's saved in kafka.

Here's my app.py code as of now

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2009 Facebook
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
# not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
# a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
# WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
# License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

import logging
import tornado.escape
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import os.path
import uuid

from tornado.concurrent import Future
from tornado import gen
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line
from pykafka import KafkaClient


define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)
define("debug", default=False, help="run in debug mode")


class MessageBuffer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.waiters = set()
        self.cache = []
        self.cache_size = 200

    def wait_for_messages(self, cursor=None):
        # Construct a Future to return to our caller.  This allows
        # wait_for_messages to be yielded from a coroutine even though
        # it is not a coroutine itself.  We will set the result of the
        # Future when results are available.
        result_future = Future()
        if cursor:
            new_count = 0
            for msg in reversed(self.cache):
                if msg["id"] == cursor:
                    break
                new_count += 1
            if new_count:
                result_future.set_result(self.cache[-new_count:])
                return result_future
        self.waiters.add(result_future)
        return result_future

    def cancel_wait(self, future):
        self.waiters.remove(future)
        # Set an empty result to unblock any coroutines waiting.
        future.set_result([])

    def new_messages(self, messages):
        logging.info("Sending new message to %r listeners", len(self.waiters))
        for future in self.waiters:
            future.set_result(messages)
        self.waiters = set()
        self.cache.extend(messages)
        if len(self.cache) > self.cache_size:
            self.cache = self.cache[-self.cache_size:]

client = KafkaClient(hosts="127.0.0.1:9092")
topic = client.topics['test']
consumer = topic.get_simple_consumer()
for message in consumer:
    if message is not None:
        print message.value
# Making this a non-singleton is left as an exercise for the reader.
global_message_buffer = MessageBuffer()


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html", messages=global_message_buffer.cache)


class MessageNewHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        message = {
            "id": str(uuid.uuid4()),
            "body": self.get_argument("body"),
        }
        # to_basestring is necessary for Python 3's json encoder,
        # which doesn't accept byte strings.
        message["html"] = tornado.escape.to_basestring(
            self.render_string("message.html", message=message))
        if self.get_argument("next", None):
            self.redirect(self.get_argument("next"))
        else:
            self.write(message)
        global_message_buffer.new_messages([message])


class MessageUpdatesHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        cursor = self.get_argument("cursor", None)
        # Save the future returned by wait_for_messages so we can cancel
        # it in wait_for_messages
        self.future = global_message_buffer.wait_for_messages(cursor=cursor)
        messages = yield self.future
        if self.request.connection.stream.closed():
            return
        self.write(dict(messages=messages))

    def on_connection_close(self):
        global_message_buffer.cancel_wait(self.future)


def main():
    parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
        [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/a/message/new", MessageNewHandler),
            (r"/a/message/updates", MessageUpdatesHandler),
            ],
        cookie_secret="__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
        template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
        static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
        xsrf_cookies=True,
        debug=options.debug,
        )
    app.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but in case it is useful to somebody else, it *is* possible to use tornado and the python-kafka module together (though @sixstone's suggestion of using kiel is also a good one).

Since python-kafaka is blocking, and we also need the tornado main loop to be running, we need separate the threads. In the following (longish) example I create a thread for the python-kafka call, and keep the tornado IOLoop in the main thread.

The example is fairly lengthy because it also makes use of websockets to publish the messages as soon as they are recieved. Hopefully the added complexity is worth the extra few lines for those wanting to combine real-time notifications through websockets with tornado and kafka.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

import collections
import threading

import jinja2
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket


# A global to store some history...
message_history = collections.deque([], maxlen=100)


class KafkaWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    # Keep track of open sockets globally, so that we can 
    # communicate with them conveniently.
    open_sockets = set()

    @classmethod
    def write_to_all(cls, message):
        removable = set()
        for ws in cls.open_sockets:
            if not ws.ws_connection or not ws.ws_connection.stream.socket:
                removable.add(ws)
            else:
                ws.write_message(message)
        for ws in removable:
            cls.open_sockets.remove(ws)

    def open(self):
        # We don't want these sockets to be buffered.
        self.set_nodelay(True)
        type(self).open_sockets.add(self)


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    template = """
<html>
<head>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
{{ messages|length }} messages in cache:
<br><br>
<div id="messages">
{% for message in messages %}
 <div>{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
    Web socket status: <div id="message">Not connected</div>
      </div>
    </footer>

<script>

var loc = window.location, new_uri;
if (loc.protocol === "https:") {
    new_uri = "wss:";
} else {
    new_uri = "ws:";
}
new_uri += "//" + loc.host;
new_uri += loc.pathname + "ws";

var ws = new WebSocket(new_uri);
var $message = $('#message');
ws.onopen = function(){
  $message.attr("class", 'label label-success');
  $message.text('open');
};
ws.onmessage = function(ev){
  $message.attr("class", 'label label-info');
  $message.hide();
  $message.fadeIn("slow");
  $message.text('recieved message ' + new Date().toLocaleString());
  $('#messages').append("<div>" + ev.data + "</div>")
};
ws.onclose = function(ev){
  $message.attr("class", 'label label-important');
  $message.text('closed');
};
ws.onerror = function(ev){
  $message.attr("class", 'label label-warning');
  $message.text('error occurred');
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
"""
    def get(self):
        env = jinja2.Environment()
        template = env.from_string(self.template)
        self.write(template.render(messages=message_history))


class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    daemon = True

    def __init__(self, kafka_consumer):
        self._consumer = kafka_consumer
        super(Consumer, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        for message in self._consumer:
            message = str(message)
            message_history.append(message)
            KafkaWebSocket.write_to_all(message)


def make_app(*args, **kwargs):
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/?", MainHandler),
        (r"/ws/?", KafkaWebSocket),
    ], *args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    kafka_consumer = Consumer(KafkaConsumer('mytopic'))
    # Start the kafka consumer thread.
    kafka_consumer.start()

    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8889)

    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    io_loop.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/560, the most closed solution to Java in python is not compatible with any async framework (asyncio, twisted or tornado), so we have to use another library which is compatible with tornado. The following one works for me:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kiel